# MySQL - Retornando alguns registros somente se agrupados

Tags: mysql

Tenho um sistema simples de formulário que registra no banco a quantidade de prestações diárias de uma pessoa na empresa.

O banco de dados não retorna esses dados na maioria dos casos. O problema começou acontecer depois que, na semana passada, os HD's do servidor terem queimado. Conseguimos recuperar os databases, mas voltou com esse problema.

Um exemplo do que acontece:

Suponhamos que eu registre pelo sistema:

```
ID: 11 | Prestação: Atendimento | Quantidade: 10| 

ID: 12 | Prestação: Palestra    | Quantidade: 5 |

ID: 13 | Prestação: Audiências  | Quantidade: 2 |
```

Se eu fizer um `SELECT` no banco usando o `ID` da prestação específico, o registro **não é trazido, mesmo ele estando no banco**:

```
select * from prestacoes where prestacao_id = 11;
```

Se eu fizer outro `SELECT` usando `IN()`, o registro que não retornava anteriormente (11), retorna junto com outro:

```
select * from prestacoes where prestacao_id in(11,12)
```

O pior de tudo é que isso acontece com apenas alguns registros específicos. Suponhamos que os registros com o problema são os ID's 11 e 13, o 12 retorna normalmente.

Suspeitamos de dados corrompidos mas ainda assim não faz sentido, sendo que o database de homologação está com o mesmo problema há uma semana. Antes disso, estava perfeito.

Comment: Nunca passei por uma situação assim, mas talvez uma solução seja migrar os dados para outra tabela (caso o problema seja apenas nessa tambela) ou para outra _database_, caso outras tabelas apresentem o mesmo problema.

Comment: Como vocês fizeram para recuperar os DBs? Se eu fosse chutar, foi feita alguma conversão. Confira também o tipo da coluna ID.

Comment: Podemos tentar ajudar a achar o erro, mas o jeito mais fácil (o passo que eu tentaria) é o que o Kadu disse.

Comment: Então, foi feito um dump. Por fim, foi feito um MySQL Check e a resposta é que estava tudo certo. Mas ainda sim suspeito de que está corrompido.

Answer (score 1):

O que pode estar ocorrendo pode ser tanto problemas no seu mysql, como problema no information_schema, como um problema de dados corrompidos no seu banco de dados.

Você pode tentar reparar todas as tabelas do seu banco utilizando a instrução abaixo:

```
SELECT CONCAT('repair table ', table_name, ';') 
FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'NOMEDOSEUBANCO';
concat('repair table ', table_name, ';');
```

Ou tentar reparar uma única tabela, assim:

```
repair table SUA_TABELA;
```

E ver se isso resolve seu problema.
Para mais informações, consulte:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/repair-table.html